# Windows Installation on MacBook Pro

Tags: mac, windows

I am keen on installing Windows 8.1 or 10 on my MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013). Some say Windows don't work well as OS X interferes with it. Is it so ?

Comment: Which version of OS X do you have installed. Which version of Windows do you want to install? What is the model year of your Mac Pro? Do you intend to have both OS X and Windows installed or just Windows installed? Does your Mac pro have more than one internal drive?

Comment: windows 8.1 or 10. Model is MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013). I intend to have both OS X and Windows installed. processor 2.4 GHz Intel Core i5

Comment: Just to let you know. A Mac Pro is an entirely different machine from a MacBook Pro. A Mac Pro is contained in a desktop case like a traditional PC.

Comment: Thank you for your help David, so do you think I could install windows on me Macbook Pro?

Comment: The answer is yeas you can install it. But the second part is not answererable - what do you mean does not work well and if installed via BootCamp there is no OSX

Comment: Thanks Mark.. But some users say that they face lots of difficulty with OS X  & windows on the same laptop. But as I see it one works on one thing at a time so there should be no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows runs on a Mac independent of the Mac operation system (OS X). Included in OS X is a utility called the Boot Camp Assistant which aids in installing officially support versions of Windows. In your case, both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 are supported. You will need a 16 GB or larger flash drive to install Windows on your model Mac. While I personally have only installed Windows 10 on iMacs, I would assume you should not have any problems installing on your MacBook Pro.

Once Windows is installed, you will be able to boot between the Windows and OS X. Windows can be selected from the OS X System Preferences application. OS X can be selected from the Windows Control Panel or directly from the Desktop.

More information can be found at the Apple web site: [How to install Windows using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468).

Comment: That was really helpful. Thanks a lot for your advice and gratitude to you for having spared your valuable time.

Comment: @Jas Make sure to mark the answer as accepted (click the green check mark) so that future users know that this helped answer your question.